# Weird behavior with datetime: error: time data '0' does not match format '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I know this has been asked 1000 times before but what i am experiencing is really weird and I cant troubleshoot it.

I have a date column structured like this:

> 24JUN2017:14:46:57

I use:

> pd.to_datetime('24JUN2017:14:46:57', format="%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")

and it works fine.

But when I try to input the whole column:

> pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'], format="%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")

I get the error of the title. Anyone knows why I might be experiencing this?

ps:I have checked for any empty spaces and there are none

Comment: There are some bad data, need `pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'], format="%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S", errors='coerce')`

Comment: Well `0` doesn't match, did you see if you had this value in your column?

Comment: Thanks a lot you two. I had bad data in my column. Stupid little mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by jezrael and EdChum, i have bd data in my column. errors='coerce' option solved this problem.